# Looking for a formula that recognises different digits in a cell

Tags: excel, formula

I am creating a spreadsheet where the user can enter different numbers and have a different result be returned.

For example if they were to enter a number that started 07, it would show 1, 070 it would show 2, 0345 3 and so on.

I have tried the IF and LEFT formulas but I am struggling!

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry I was trying not to write war and peace but have missed out too much.

The users will write in phone area codes, e.g. 0345 or 0714 or 0701 and the sheet will return the price.

The price can be different depending on the first 4 digits. To keep it simple for this purpose I want it to be able to detect if the area code starts with 07 to show a "price" of 1, 070 price of 2 and 0345 a price of 3.

I have 10 different area codes but just added the 3 above for examples.

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: So should it display the number of significant digits?

Comment: What formulas did you try?  What were they returning?

Comment: Why would `07` return `1` and `0345` return `3`? I don't understand. Could you just do `=LEN(0+A1)` (totally guessing that the logic is to get a number of characters after any leading 0's???).

Comment: Apologies I've added an edit above!

Answer (score 4):

To get the length of a string with the leading zeros removed use the array function

```
 =LEN(MID(A2,MATCH(TRUE,(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)<>"0"),0),LEN(A2)))
```

Replace A2 with the cell that the users will change and hit [Ctrl Shift Enter] on the cell with the formula to activate the array function.

Comment: Why not simply use `=LEN(--A2)`

Comment: I think this is worth a vote because it works for any string (e.g. 000ABC), otherwise if it's purely a number  @JNevill's or Scott Craner's comment.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ooooh.. I didn't know that formula. It is a lot simpler and fits the OP's request as written.  If you post it I'll upvote it as a good answer!

Comment: OP didn't say they had to be decimal numbers...

Comment: @TomSharpe OP did not say much about the inputs or why the expected outputs.